# A problem about range of value

Tags: real-analysis, matrices

Suppose that $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$，$g(x)$ is a function which satisfies Lipschitz condition on $[0,1]$. Let $\phi(t)=(f(t),g(t))$.Prove that $\phi([0,1])$ not contains $[0,1]\times [0,1]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lipschitz functions map sets of measure $0$ to sets of measure $0$ [hence also Lebesgue measurable sets to Lebesgue measurable sets]. Note that $(x,y) \in \phi([0,1]\times [0,1])$ implies $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$ for some $t$ which implies $y \in g(f^{-1}(x))$. If $\mu$ is two dimensional Lebesgue  measure it follows that $\mu (\phi ([0,1]\times [0,1]) \leq \int m(g(f^{-1}(x))dx$ by Fubini's Theorem (where $m$ is one dimensional Lebesgue measure). If we show that $m(g(f^{-1}(x))=0$ for all but countable many $x$ we can conclude that $\phi([0,1]\times [0,1])$  is actually  set of measure $0$. Now the sets $f^{-1}(x)$ ($0\leq x \leq 1$) are pairwise disjoint so there are at most $n$ values of $x$ for which $m(f^{-1}(x)) >\frac 1 n$. The union of these sets is therefore countable.